# Two different page-counters in critical editions, part 2

Tags: koma-script, page-numbering, counters, mark

In [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/378376/two-different-page-counters-in-critical-editions) question, David Carlisle provided some code to create a second page-counter in the header to indicate pages and page-breaks for critical editions. This is pretty cool. However, as documents grow complex, I run into problems. Here is a MWE detailing two:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}
\ohead{\textbf{\pagemark}}
\def\lastoldpagemark{\topmarks\oldpagemark}
\ihead{\textit{\lastoldpagemark\ifnum\lastoldpagemark<\botmarks\oldpagemark--\botmarks\oldpagemark\fi
               \xdef\lastoldpagemark{\botmarks\oldpagemark}}}
\ofoot{}
\pagestyle{scrheadings}
\newmarks\oldpagemark % etex marks not completely reliable in latex, but probably OK here
\newcounter{oldpage}
\setcounter{oldpage}{1}

\newcommand{\markoldpage}{
[mark]
\marks\oldpagemark{\theoldpage}\marginpar{\centering\footnotesize\theoldpage}
\stepcounter{oldpage}
}

\begin{document}

\chapter{First Chapter}
\markoldpage{} This is the first oldpage. 

\markoldpage{} Now the second oldpage has begun. 
\lipsum[1]
\lipsum[3] \markoldpage{} 
\lipsum \markoldpage{} 
\lipsum[1-10] \markoldpage{}
\lipsum[1]

\chapter{Second Chapter}
\section{First Section}
\setcounter{oldpage}{20}
\markoldpage{} This is the first oldpage. \markoldpage{} Now the second oldpage has begun.

\newpage

\lipsum[1-3] \markoldpage{} \lipsum[1-3] \markoldpage{}

\section{Second Section}
\setcounter{oldpage}{17} \markoldpage
\lipsum[1] 

\end{document}
```

1. Sometimes, the oldpage counter in the page *following* a new chapter
   is incorrect, as exemplified on pages two and six of the output. Can
   someone help me understand what’s going on?
2. If I place a new item on the *same* page which has a *lower oldpage*
   (e.g. with a `\section` instead of a `\chapter` as indicated in the
   MWE), then, of course, the page-counter also doesn’t work, as the
   macro only specifies this for larger oldpage-numbers. Would it be
   possible in this case to use the marks to typeset it like this:
   [OldpageSection1], [OldpageSection2]

Comment: topmarks is not reliable in latex as latex can call the output routine more than once while creating a page.

Comment: Is it possible to employ a mechanism that doesn’t rely on \topmarks?

Comment: I don't remember what this was about and I don't have the time to look, but you could check if the new marks code in a current latex (texdoc ltmarks) helps you.

Comment: Looks very promising! I’ll give it a try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The new mark-system described in [ltmarks](https://www.latex-project.org/help/documentation/ltmarks-doc.pdf) (maybe to be read together with the new LaTeX-Companion, I, pp. 390–395) provides an easy mechanism to achieve the desired outcome.

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}
\addtokomafont{pagenumber}{\bfseries}

\NewMarkClass{oldpagemark}

\newcounter{oldpage}
\setcounter{oldpage}{1}

\ohead{\pagemark}

\ihead{\IfMarksEqualTF{oldpagemark}{top}{last}{(\TopMark{oldpagemark})}{(\TopMark{oldpagemark}--\LastMark{oldpagemark})}}
\ofoot{}

\pagestyle{scrheadings}

\newcommand{\markoldpage}{¦\stepcounter{oldpage}\InsertMark{oldpagemark}{\theoldpage}\marginpar{\centering\footnotesize\theoldpage}}

\begin{document}

\chapter{First chapter}
\lipsum[1-2] \markoldpage{}
\lipsum[1-10] \markoldpage{}
\lipsum[1-2] \markoldpage{}
\lipsum[1-4] \markoldpage{}

\chapter{Second chapter with new numbering} \setcounter{oldpage}{43}
\lipsum[1-2] \markoldpage{}
\lipsum[1-4] \markoldpage{}
\lipsum[1-2] \markoldpage{}
\lipsum[1-4] \markoldpage{}

\chapter{Third chapter with new numbering} \setcounter{oldpage}{25}
\lipsum[1-2] \markoldpage{}
\lipsum[1-4] \markoldpage{}
\lipsum[1-2] \markoldpage{}
\lipsum[1-4] \markoldpage{}

\end{document}
```

Some prose descriptions: Since 2022, `\NewMarkClass` provides a mark-mechanism that doesn’t run into problems like eTeX’s marks and primitive TeX’s mark-commands like `\topmark` when compiled with LaTeX.

The new corresponding commands `\TopMark`, `\LastMark` and `\InsertMark` enable LaTeX to grab the relevant page-numbering-information without interfering.

`\markoldpage` makes use of these features in combination with a counter (`oldpage`) which is simply marked at the correct location via `\InsertMark`.

`\IfMarksEqualTF` then uses a simple conditional also defined in [ltmarks](https://www.latex-project.org/help/documentation/ltmarks-doc.pdf) to print the correct information in the header. The bold numbers represent the page-numbers of the document, and the italic numbers in brackets represent the oldpage-numbers. The character signifying a page-break (»¦«) and the numbering of the old-page in the margin are also added.

Depending on the page range of the, lets say, »phantom-oldpage-numbering«, either a single digit number is written in the header if the range is one, e.g. here on output-page 2 ...

[image]

... or a page-range if it is larger than one, e.g. output page 10.

[image]

Previously, I ran into problems as soon as I changed the counter-value between chapters, but this seems to be fine, so far!